# How to use ActiveAdmin with TailwindCSS Rails without Tailwind styles breaking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, activeadmin

I am using `tailwindcss-rails` gem along with Flowbite(fyi). I developed a whole app on top of those two and recently I needed to add an admin gem to the app. I really like ActiveAdmin, but as soon as I add it and `sassc-rails` all of the app's style breaks and it doesn't use Tailwind classes. Because if I don't add `sassc-rails` ActiveAdmin won't run.

How can I make these two work together?

There is not much more I can add to the question, but if you need more info or some code snippets, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by following [this answer](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3819#issuecomment-351377822)

Basically you need to move `active_admin.js` from `app/assets/javascripts` to `vendor/assets/javascripts`(you need to create these folders), and moving `active_admin.scss` from `app/assets/stylesheets` to `vendor/assets/stylesheets`.

Even though that was in the answer, it still didn't work, so if it doesn't for you, just do the following that helped me:

In `vendor/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss`:

```scss
// From this
@import "mixins";
@import "base";

// To this
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";
```

And in `vendor/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`:

```js
//= require active_admin/base
```

Replace it with this in case you have some relative path appended that didn't work.